# SpaCy doc.similarity limitations

Tags: nlp, spacy, information-retrieval, sentence-similarity

I'm building an information retrieval tool that receives an user's request and returns the most similar label in the corpus.

With Spacy's vanilla similarity, I have the following limitation :

```
request = nlp("cute cat")

label1 = nlp("cute dog")
label2 = nlp("lovable cat")

print(request.similarity(label1))
print(request.similarity(label2))

# Returns 
# 0.9046133562567831
# 0.8776915657921017
```

In this case I would like cat label to have a higher similarity because the request is about a (cute/lovable/...) cat.
Also, "ugly cat" should have a lower score then "cute dog".

I'm thinking of overwriting Spacy's similarity so doc.similarity will be a weighted sum of similarity between nouns and similarity between adjectives. The first one will have a higher weight.

**Do you think it would be a good idea ? Do you know better ways or tools for this ?**

Also, labels are not that simple. I'm thinking of dependency parsing to handle labels as "cute dog in a garden" (I'm inventing them). Here *dog* and *garden* are nouns but *dog* is the 'main' one.

Comment: I'm using the lg model

Comment: Weighting nouns might work, but you're probably better off training a custom similarity model. Look into question answering or metric learning.